# Laptop external monitor turning green

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

My laptop is a Dell XPS 15 L502x with GT540M graphics and i5 2450M processor . When I connect to an external monitor , any external monitor (I use the Dell S2216H) , the screen shows weird patterns like green dots all over a black screen or a solid color all over the screen . Some times it would come back , saying "NVIDIA Kernel Mode Driver failed and has successfully recovered " . Does anybody know the problem ? I read that this is about the laptop GPU overheating - is this the problem ?

Steps I have taken- are -

- Tried installing monitor drivers
- Tried disabling one of my GPU's (Intel Integrated or NVIDIA)

Nothing has worked - what should I do to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your graphics card is falling... heat problems often contribute to shortening the life of PC/laptop components - especially CPU and GPU.

I've had numerous users with NVidia on-board GPUs and when you power the laptop on, the heat generated is often very high, and the culprit is dust or dried heatsink paste.